# Where clause not pulling the correct data from table

Tags: mysql

My subs table has the the following columns:
idSubs, LastName, FirstName, Phone, Email, Type

My subProjects table has these columns:idSubs, idProjects, PaidOutAmount

I am trying to get the minimum amount and the maximum amount that appears in PaidOutAmount. I also want the contractors Lastname these amounts were paid to.

I run the following:

```
Select min(PaidOutAmount) least, subs.LastName as PaidTo,   
max(PaidOutAmount) max, subs.LastName as PaidTo
from subprojects, subs 
where subprojects.idSubs = subs.idSubs
```

The resultant table is:

```
least   PaidTo   max      PaidTo
126.00  Torrey  5650.55   Torrey
```

This is what I want, except the name that appears under the first "PaidTo" column is "Torrey" and it should be "Bassler". In my subProjects table, the minimum amount is 126.00 but the idSubs is 6. If I go to my subs table, 6 in fact refers to the contractor with the last name of Bassler. 
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

From Jorge's answer I tried the following:

```
Select subs.Lastname as PaidTo, PaidOutAmount as Value from subprojects,
subs where subprojects.idSubs = subs.idSubs and PaidOutAmount =    
min(PaidOutAmount) or PaidOutAmount = max(PaidOutAmount)
```

After finding elsewhere on stackoverflow that max is not valid with a where clause and that a subquery should be used, I changed it to this:

```
Select subs.Lastname as PaidTo, PaidOutAmount as Value from subprojects,
subs where subprojects.idSubs = subs.idSubs and (select PaidOutAmount =  
min(PaidOutAmount)or PaidOutAmount = max(PaidOutAmount))
```

This produces a table with all subs and all PaidOutAmounts. In other words it is not extracting only the minimum and maximum values like I am trying to do. After experimenting I discovered that any configuration or variation of the above simply produces the same results as if I simply use the following:

```
Select subs.Lastname as PaidTo, PaidOutAmount as Value from subprojects,
subs
```

What might be the problem?

Sorry for being dense, I just am not seeing the problem.  As per your suggestion I went to SQlFiddle. I modified your suggested query as such:

```
SELECT
 subs.LastName AS PaidTo, subprojects.PaidOutAmount as Value
FROM subprojects AS S
  INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
              idSubs
            , MIN(PaidOutAmount) MinPaidOutAmount
            , MAX(PaidOutAmount) MaxPaidOutAmount
        FROM subprojects
        GROUP BY
              idSubs
  ) AS
  subs ON S.idSubs = subs.idSubs
 WHERE S.PaidOutAmount =  subs.MinPaidOutAmount
  OR S.PaidOutAmount = subs.MaxPaidOutAmount
```

The  relevant tables that I put into SqlFiddle is this:

```
CREATE TABLE subs
(idSubs int(11) NOT NULL ,
LastName VARCHAR(20),
FirstName VARCHAR(15)  ,
Phone VARCHAR(10)  ,
Email VARCHAR(45)  ,
Type VARCHAR(15),
PRIMARY KEY (`idSubs`));

CREATE TABLE  subprojects (
idSubs int(11) NOT NULL ,
idProjects INT(11) NOT NULL,
PaidOutAmount DECIMAL(7,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`idSubs`, `idProjects`));

INSERT INTO SubProjects VALUES (1, 200, 755.23);
INSERT INTO SubProjects VALUES (6, 200, 126.00);
INSERT INTO SubProjects VALUES (8, 200, 2523.53);
INSERT INTO SubProjects VALUES (1, 300, 5650.55);
INSERT INTO SubProjects VALUES (6, 300, 750.19);
INSERT INTO SubProjects VALUES (7, 300, 2500.00);
INSERT INTO SubProjects VALUES (8, 100, 374.14);



INSERT INTO Subs VALUES    
(1,'Torrey','Brian','5635435877','torrey@torrey.com', 'Carpenter');
INSERT INTO Subs  VALUES (2, 'McDonough', 'Mark', '5635997115',   
'McDonough@gmail.com', 'Carpenter');
INSERT INTO Subs VALUES (3, 'Basler', 'Bruce', '5635904457',  
'BB@yahoo.com', 'Carpenter');
INSERT INTO Subs  VALUES (4, 'ThePainter', 'Tyler', '5635800330',  
'paintpros@gmail.com', 'Painter');
INSERT INTO Subs VALUES (5, 'ThePainter2', 'Adam', '5635642819',  
'adampnt@gmail.com', 'Painter');
INSERT INTO Subs VALUES (6, 'A&G', 'Dean', '5635902919',  
'dean12@agelectric.com', 'Electrician');
INSERT INTO Subs VALUES (7, 'AllSeasons', 'Dean', '5635431296',  
'service@allseasons.com', 'Heating/Cooling');
INSERT INTO Subs VALUES (8, 'Gregory', 'Tom', '5634950997',   
'tgregory@floorshowcompanies.com', 'Flooring');
INSERT INTO Subs VALUES (9, 'Jaeger', 'Kevin', '5635836677',   
'kevin@jaegerplmb.com', 'Plumbing');
```

Comment: Thats imho an odd output structure. You can try something like `Select subs.Lastname as PaidTo, PaidOutAmount as Value from subprojects, subs where subproject.idSubs = subs.idSubs and (PaidOutAmount = min(PaidOutAmount) or PaidOutAmount = max(PaidOutAmount))`. You should get a two-column result set `(PaidTo, Value)` with two tuples, one tuple with the most amount and last name and one tuple with the least amount and the last name

Comment: It seems you didn't understand well grouping functions. Someone else will care to explain in a moment. I'm to lazy now...

Comment: Thanks Jorge. I get Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function, however when I try it. I tried moving the brackets in different ways to no avail.

Comment: You will get better/faster resolution to your questions if you provide `sample data` and `expected results` and/or setup a fiddle, see http://sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0):

To filter on aggregates you need:

- a. to GROUP the data, and
- b. use the HAVING clause

But your query needs something else - a subquery, something like this:

```
SELECT
      s.*
FROM subprojects AS S
      INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                  idSubs
                , MIN(PaidOutAmount) MinPaidOutAmount
                , MAX(PaidOutAmount) MaxPaidOutAmount
            FROM subprojects
            GROUP BY
                  idSubs
      ) AS
      subs ON S.idSubs = subs.idSubs
WHERE S.PaidOutAmount =  subs.MinPaidOutAmount
      OR S.PaidOutAmount = subs.MaxPaidOutAmount
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'subs.Lastname' in 'field list'

Comment: sorry, that was a carry over from a copy/paste. Just adjust the first select clause to suit your needs, I have just changed it to read s.*

Comment: please note as I have none of your data or tables to work with, if things error out I can't really help too much

Comment: I am using subs.Lastname for my select and I still get error code 1054. LastName is a column in my subs table. These even show  up in the drop down suggestions. So it recognizes the table and column but according to the error code, it is unknown.

Comment: do please read the query - it is different, my subquery has only 3 columns none of which are Lastname. use S.Lastname instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this convoluted mess is going to have to do I guess, but it actually works to get the info I wanted. If anyone would like to tell me how to do it better that would we fantastic.

```
select
(select min(PaidOutAmount)
 from  subprojects) as min,
 (Select Lastname
 from subs, subprojects 
 where subs.idSubs = subprojects.idSubs
 order by PaidOutAmount asc
 limit 1) as PaidTo,
 (Select max(PaidOutAmount) from subprojects) as Max,
(Select Lastname
from subs, subprojects 
where subs.idSubs = subprojects.idSubs
order by PaidOutAmount desc
limit 1) as PaidTo
```

It produes this:

```
min     PaidTo    Max      PaidTo
126.00   A&G    5650.55     Torrey
```

This works too.

```
SELECT LastName,PaidOutAmount       
FROM subs, subprojects
WHERE PaidOutAmount = (SELECT Max(PaidOutAmount)
    FROM subprojects ) and subs.idSubs = subprojects.idSubs 

 or (PaidOutAmount = (SELECT Min(PaidOutAmount)
    FROM subprojects ) and subs.idSubs = subprojects.idSubs )

LastName  PaidOutAmount
Torrey     5650.55
A&G        126.00
```